# can't use session at codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a session in my form controller the session is create when the user save 
the session affect the form page so my problem is :

if I loaded the page without clicking on save a undefined index[session index] error appears

so I created the session at the home page
but the problem is if I loaded the form page without visiting the home page at first the undefined index error appear
I tried to call the method `session_start()` but I got this error
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice Message: A session had already been started -
>   ignoring session_start() Filename: views/Form.php Line Number: 5

Comment: You seem to use a session variable after the user clicks the save button.So you may set null this variable before user clicks the save button.

Comment: post code here....

Comment: so i can help you.

Comment: $_SESSION['save']="true";
   redirect(FormController);

Comment: The above in form controller after save
this is the home controller

  $_SESSION['save']="false";
and this is 
Form

    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
     <?php if($_SESSION['save']=="true") echo "تم الحفظ بنجاح";$_SESSION['save']="false";?></label>

Comment: What is the code of the action of the form?It seems that you have to give $_SESSION['save'] a default value at the beginning of this action and then use it.

Comment: Why not use codeigniter session library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the default CI session library. You can autoload the session in `autoload.php`. Your session will start automatically, there is no need to call `session_start()`.

Then replace `$_SESSION['save']="true"` with  `$this->session->set_userdata('save', 'true');`.

I think you need to check if `session['save']` is true or not, so beforehand you must declare by default that `session['save']` is "`false`" in the default controller which is specified in the routes.php, and also make sure the `session['save']` index is already defined in your form page controller, check like this:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('save')) {
     // do something when exist
} else {
    $this->session->set_userdata('save', 'false');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are trying to implement your own session management within CI as one of the powerful tools CI offers is a flexible, simple yet powerful session management system.

Even so, surely a simple solution to your conundrum is to simply check if the session variable is set or not in your form, and if it is not set then set it to a value of 0. In your controller, you can deal with that, i.e. check if the value is 0, and if so, start a session and assign the session variable, or throw the user out, or do whatever you need you app to do when the session is not found, or is set to 0 indicating a session has not been activated.

Answer (score 1):

Your session will start automatically, there is no need to call session_start() in every controller. codeigniter session library takes care of it.

First you have to load session library. application/config/autoload.php

```
$this->load->library("session");
```

if you have loaded already no need of loading again.

To set data in session

```
$this->session->set_userdata("KEY","VALUE");
```

To get data from session

```
$this->session->userdata("KEY");
```